# How to translate Default::default() to Python equivalent?

Tags: python, rust

I'm in the process of translation some Rust code to Python.
Suppose I have some API in Rust, and methods in Python to call the Rust methods under the hood.

Example Rust (pseudo) code:

```
struct Args {
    foo: i32,
    bar: f32,
}

pub fn DummyMethod(
    &self,
    args: Args
) -> Result<Data, Error>
```

Calling this method:

```
let args = InitTxArgs {
    foo: i32,
    ..Default::default()
};
DummyMethod(args);
```

In Python I then have:

```
args = {
    'foo' : 42
    # How do I translate Default here?
}

DummyMethod(args)
```

How does one translate the ..Default in Rust to Python?
I want to specify just the foo field, without specifying the other fields.

Comment: Please explain in English words what you are trying to archive!

Comment: Python does not have struct literals, different langages provide different facilities, and your « python » doesn’t make sense. However python does have something similar in « keyword unpacking » / « duct unpacking » (depending on context), `**kwargs`.